# Wpdb generates too many queries

Tags: query, wpdb, sql

I googled for hours, then found some codes on stackexchange (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108279/108270) and created the codes below. I'm trying to get alphabetical A-Z posts lists (e.g. A B C D E ...). Everyting works fine but this code generates too many queries. When there is only post titles, page generates 15 queries but when I add `the_permalink()` it jumps to 33. I suspect there is something wrong here. Can anybody advice me a more efficient way to do what I want? Thanks in advance!

```
 global $wpdb;
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $postsperpage = 10;

 $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
     "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
     INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
     INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
     WHERE
     wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 107
     AND post_type = 'post'
     AND post_status = 'publish' 
     AND post_title LIKE %s ORDER BY post_title ASC",
     $letter . '%'
   ));
 }

 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ( $letters as $l) {
   $param = $l;
   printf('<li><a href="%s?harf=%s">%s</a></li>',$page_link, $param, $param);
 }
 echo '</ul>';

 if ($posts):
      $i = $postsperpage * ($paged-1);  
 while ( $i < $postsperpage*$paged ):
      $post = $posts[$i];
      setup_postdata($post); ?>
 <p><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
 <?php
 $i++;
 endwhile; endif;
 ?>
```

Comment: How are you defining *too many* SQL queries?

Comment: Sir, thank you for your comment but I'm afraid my English is teribble and I may misunderstand your comment. I'm using Blackbox Debugger to check the generated queries. Do you believe the code above is efficient enough? Do you think 33 queries is OK for a page that lists 10 posts with titles and permalinks? I can write Blackbox results here.

Comment: WordPress uses the database to store nearly *everything*. SQL queries are just part of the background hum of WP. I was wondering if you were experiencing slowdowns due to SQL queries, or if you just thought 33 was excessive.

Comment: According to Blackbox those extra queries have a negative impact on page load. BTW, I suspect that the part starting from `if ($posts)` also may cause the extra queries. I had to change `foreach` statement with this one.